# Attempt to randomize image generation with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, randomized-algorithm

I want to randomly generate images for a project, I'm sure it's something small but on run nothing is changing and I've been scratching my head for a couple of days now. Not too sure where the problem lies although I suspect " let SelectedImage = AIPic[RandomNumber]; " is incorrect?

THE JAVASCRIPT

````
 let RandomNumber = Math.random();
 RandomNumber = RandomNumber * AIPic.length;
 RandomNumber = Math.floor(RandomNumber);
 let SelectedImage = AIPic[RandomNumber];
 AIPics.src = SelectedImage;
 document.getElementById ('AIPics') = SelectedImage;" ```


Inside the html body - 

 <img id = "AIPics" src="loading.gif">
 <script src="script.js"></script>
````

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have those variables defined else where, this is the same code, fixed a bit:

```js
var AIPic = [
  "https://picsum.photos/id/200/200",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/201/200",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/202/200"
]
let RandomNumber = Math.random();
RandomNumber = RandomNumber * AIPic.length;
RandomNumber = Math.floor(RandomNumber);
let SelectedImage = AIPic[RandomNumber];
document.getElementById('AIPics').src = SelectedImage;
```

```html
<img id="AIPics">
```

Comment: Looks good, can u elaborate on needing to define those variables beforehand, how could I go about that

Comment: I only mean array `AIPic` should have URLs of images. Which was missing from your code.

Comment: @DMitch you cant just magically generate images. There should be images in a variable or  a database that you can pull from. The only random thing is the index of that array that contains all the pictures

Comment: oh okay sorry, yes it was in a list. this worked. thank you